# QTabWidget refusing to auto-resize

Tags: c++, qt, layout, qtabwidget

I'm attempting to have the following layout in qtcreator:

```
QWidget
  QSplitter
    QStackedWidget
      ...
    QStackedWidget
      QWidget (page)
        QTabWidget
```

Every single control that has a `sizePolicy` is set to `Expanding`. Despite this, neither the tab widget nor anything else I drop on that page widget gets autosized.

I'm new to Qt, so forgive me if this is an obvious fix. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a duplicate of
[How to make a Qt Widget grow with the window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044836/how-to-make-a-qt-widget-grow-with-the-window-size/6045152#6045152) ?

I think it is a duplicate, cause if every item in your tree of widgets has a layout, my test on Qt 4.7 gave the following output, on the right side is my object inspector.
I did just put in the widgets and layouted them, i did not change any size things to expanding, as this is absolutely unnecessary!

[image: Image with exe and creator screenshot]

On the left is the running exe, on the right is the Creator screenshot.
And here is my UI:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>545</width>
    <height>441</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QSplitter" name="splitter">
      <property name="orientation">
       <enum>Qt::Vertical</enum>
      </property>
      <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget">
       <property name="currentIndex">
        <number>0</number>
       </property>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="page_1_1">
        <property name="layoutDirection">
         <enum>Qt::LeftToRight</enum>
        </property>
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_2">
         <item row="0" column="0">
          <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget_1">
           <property name="currentIndex">
            <number>0</number>
           </property>
           <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_3">
            <attribute name="title">
             <string>Tab 1</string>
            </attribute>
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_4">
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QDateTimeEdit" name="dateTimeEdit_2"/>
             </item>
             <item row="1" column="0">
              <widget class="QDateTimeEdit" name="dateTimeEdit"/>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_4">
            <attribute name="title">
             <string>Tab 2</string>
            </attribute>
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_5">
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_2">
               <property name="text">
                <string>CheckBox</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="1" column="0">
              <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox">
               <property name="text">
                <string>CheckBox</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </widget>
      <widget class="QStackedWidget" name="stackedWidget_2">
       <widget class="QWidget" name="page_2_1">
        <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_3">
         <item row="0" column="0">
          <widget class="QTabWidget" name="tabWidget_2">
           <widget class="QWidget" name="tab">
            <attribute name="title">
             <string>Tab 1</string>
            </attribute>
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout">
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit"/>
             </item>
             <item row="1" column="0">
              <widget class="QDateEdit" name="dateEdit_2"/>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
           <widget class="QWidget" name="tab_2">
            <attribute name="title">
             <string>Tab 2</string>
            </attribute>
            <layout class="QGridLayout" name="gridLayout_6">
             <item row="0" column="0">
              <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_4">
               <property name="text">
                <string>CheckBox</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
             <item row="1" column="0">
              <widget class="QCheckBox" name="checkBox_3">
               <property name="text">
                <string>CheckBox</string>
               </property>
              </widget>
             </item>
            </layout>
           </widget>
          </widget>
         </item>
        </layout>
       </widget>
      </widget>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>545</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QToolBar" name="mainToolBar">
   <attribute name="toolBarArea">
    <enum>TopToolBarArea</enum>
   </attribute>
   <attribute name="toolBarBreak">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </attribute>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: It seems suspicious that your page widget icons look different than mine. Yours appear to have the grid layout icon, whereas mine appear to have a red (/) symbol on them. Does this mean that my pages have no layout? How would I apply a layout to my pages?

Comment: That was the problem after all. I finally figured out how to apply a layout to the page widgets.

Comment: Just to answer the comment before the last one: the red crossed icon indeed means: NO LAYOUT! And if in the hierarchy of widgets one has no layout, automatic resizing is broken!

Answer (score 2):

You need the following hierarchy note the `QLayout`):

```
QWidget
  QSplitter
    QStackedWidget
      ...
    QStackedWidget
      QWidget (page)
        QLayout
          QTabWidget
```

So the code is something like this:

```
QLayout* MyLayout = new QVBoxLayout (MyPageWidget) ;
MyLayout -> setSpacing (0) ;
MyLayout -> setContentsMargins (0, 0, 0, 0) ;
MyLayout -> addWidget (MyTabWidget) ;
```

Comment: Even if I add a layout between the tab widget and the page widget, it doesn't work. The tab widget resizes to its layout, but the layout doesn't resize to the page.

Comment: @kidneyofnothing: That's hard to believe! How do you know?

Answer (score 1):

I created a new top level window (QWidget) in designer and drop two stacked widgets on it, ctrl-click both of them to select them and then right-clicked them and selected "Layout Horizontally in Splitter". I then right clicked on the top level QWidget and selected "Layout in a Grid". After this, the two stacked widgets expand to fill the avaialable space and they properly grow and shrink with the top level window. Perhaps you just need to set a layout for the top level widget?

Comment: The two stacked widgets had already been expanding properly. It's the control on the inside of the stacked widget (inside of the stacked page) that doesn't resize.