# Qt & Qt Designer - Making widget fill the parent without padding

Tags: qt, layout, user-interface, qt-creator, qt-designer

I wanted to make my widget fill the parent window, even when the window resizes, so I read this: [How to make a Qt Widget grow with the window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044836/how-to-make-a-qt-widget-grow-with-the-window-size)

But this solution created a new problem: my widget automatically re-sizes to the size of the window, but there's padding on the sides of the window. I want the widget to *completely* fill the parent, and it's not doing that. Look:

---

[image]

---

Here you can see that the tab widget doesn't entirely fill the parent. I've done some research and have seen that *through programming*, you can configure the layout to get rid of this padding. Problem is, I'm building my GUI in *QDesigner*, so I can't just go `layout->setMargin(0);`

My question is, how to I get rid of this padding on the sides of my window *through Qt Designer?*

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In the bottom of central widget properties there is a section of Layout (it is red), where you can set layout margins. Also, you still can do it programmatically:

```
QMainWindow::centralWidget()->layout()->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: I found the layout section, and I fixed it. Also, I didn't know you could access the central widget until now, so thank you very much!