# Making Qt Widgets Stretch and Scale w/ Main Window

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, widget, qmainwindow

I'm wondering if there is a way to make Qt widgets within a QMainWindow widget stretch and scale as the size of the main window is stretched and shrunk. Basically, I'd like the entire window and it's contents to have the same appearance except for size:
[image]

At the only way I can think to accomplish this is to get the size of the main window, do the math for every single widget, and reset their sizes any time the main window size is changed, but I'm thinking there's an easier way.

Comment: some code could help a bit, but if i understand you right, you can use layouts. they will do it automatically. make a new widget, put all your widget inside this by using layouts, and make this new widget to the `central` (by setCentralWidget) widget of the mainwindow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a Qt Widget grow with the window size?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044836/how-to-make-a-qt-widget-grow-with-the-window-size)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like this video tutorial on [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7Ud6FonsR4).  I'll help you create a layout using QLayout classes.  If you use QtCreator/Designer, you can also take a look at the auto-generated ui_MainWindow.XXX file that will clue you in on how it uses some of the UI classes.

As always, QtCreator/Designer has a bunch of hints and tips so you should be able to dig up from the documentation that's embedded in the application.