# How to activate centralWidget in QT Designer

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I was looking at this article
[How to make a Qt Widget grow with the window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044836/how-to-make-a-qt-widget-grow-with-the-window-size/6045152#6045152)
but when i got to the answer I got stuck on "activating" the central widget.  I notice an icon with a red circle so I guess that means its disabled.  I've been searching the net to try to figure out how to "activate" it but I am not having any luck.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 6):

Have a look at the layout system.
That icon does not mean your QWidget is disabled, that just mean you do not apply a layout on it.
Try to press like Ctrl+1 in order to apply a basic layout. If nothing has changed, you might need to put a QWidget inside the central widget first and then apply the layout.