# Make QGraphicsView size fit

Tags: c++, qt, size, qgraphicsview

I would like to make a QGraphicsView just fit in a QMainWiondw of fixed size.
And I need the coordinate of the top left corner to be (0,0).
How can I do this?

This is my main function

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow window;
    window.setFixedSize(1440, 900);

    window.show();

    return a.exec();
}
```

This is the MainWindow constructor.

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    view = new QGraphicsView(this);
    scene = new QGraphicsScene(0, 0, 1440, 900, this);
    view->setScene(scene);
    setCentralWidget(view);

    drawCoordinate(0,0);
}
```

There is a scroll appeared. I think it is deal to the title bar.

I don't really mind the size of the QGraphicsView as long as the size of the mainwindow is fixed. But I need the QGraphicsView to fill the whole mainwindow without a scroll bar and the top left corner of the  mainwindow is located at (0, 0).

With @tangerine help, I can make the program like this. But there is still space between the main window and the graphic view.
[image: Program Output]

This is what I hope to achieve:
[image]

The (0, 0) coordinate starts at the topmost and leftmost of the mainwindow.

Comment: I had the same problem. Solved with `view->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft | Qt::AlignTop);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a layout for the main window and put the graphics view into it. You can find more about this topic here: [How to make a Qt Widget grow with the window size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044836/how-to-make-a-qt-widget-grow-with-the-window-size)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly I think you should add this string in the MainWindow constructor:
`view->fitInView(scene->sceneRect(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I appreciate your help. It makes the scene fit into the view. But the only problem is the view is not fit into the mainwindow.