# Make QListWidget fill QFormLayout

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-designer

I am using QT4 Designer have a layout that looks basically like this:

```
QWidget
  QVBoxLayout
    QFormLayout
      QLineEdit
      QListWidget
      QPushButton
```

Each control is on a separate line.

I did the [layout assignment trick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6045152/1270789) to get everything to fit to the parent, and if I reduce the height the `QListWidget` shrinks as hoped, but if I increase the height the `QWidget.geometry.Height` never exceeds 192. The `Vertical Policy` is set to `Expanding` and the `maximumSize.Height` is 16777215, but no other policy seems to allow the `QListWidget` to grow. Width grows correctly, however.

What setting am I missing? Should I instead anchor the `QPushButton` to the bottom of the `QFormLayout`, and if so, how?

Comment: you could provide a [mcve] of your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found my own answer - I selected the `QFormLayout`, right-clicked, and chose `Lay out/Lay Out in a Grid` and everything snapped into place! So, the new, working hierarchy is:

```
QWidget
  QVBoxLayout
    QGridLayout  <<-- Changed from QFormLayout
      QLineEdit
      QListWidget
      QPushButton
```