# QT Align Controls depending upon Screen Resolution

Tags: qt

How to Align Controls depending upon Screen Resolution in Qt ?

I have created UI in QtCreator now when i expand the form the controls inside it remains the same size.

Thanks.

Comment: You probably missed to set a layout on the centralWidget. See my detailed answer in a similar question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249224/controls-insist-on-being-too-large-and-wont-resize-in-qtdesigner/5358269#5358269)

Answer (score 2):

Use Layouts. [Here](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/layout.html) is general description of them.