# How to make QScrollArea change size according to QDialog?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QDialog like this:

[image]

I have added a QScrollArea to this QDialog like this:

[image]

What I want is **When the user expands QDialog , the QScrollArea should also expand with it**.

I have tried several properties of `QScrollArea` like `verticalScrollBarPolicy`
`horizontalScrollBarPolicy`, `sizeAdjustPolicy`, but nothing seems to work.

Can someone suggest how to accomplish this?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249224/controls-insist-on-being-too-large-and-wont-resize-in-qtdesigner) maybe?

Comment: Please check link above provided by Steeve .. that will solve your issue

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Controls insist on being too large, and won't resize, in QtDesigner](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5249224/controls-insist-on-being-too-large-and-wont-resize-in-qtdesigner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the dialog to resize its child widgets, it must have a layout. Set a layout on the dialog. Do not change any of `QScrollArea`'s properties: they only affect the area itself and its children, and have nothing to do with how the parent widget (the dialog) might manage the scroll area's `geometry()`.