# How to make a Widget full size to the window with QT Creator?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

Helo,

when i rightclick to the window background I get this:

[image]

Why are the Layout options are not clickable?

I want to extend a widget to the window.

Comment: What is the context ? What widget are you editing ? What is its parent ? Root widget (which actually is the window) will automatically take all your window space, as it is the window. But hard to help without more details

Comment: I guess I'm not following, but if you want to set properties of a widget, you need to click that widget.

Comment: Look at one of the many Qt Designer tutorials on for example youtube, they cover that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42293585/how-to-make-qscrollarea-change-size-according-to-qdialog